# Reduplication of Adverb + Adjective in 很细很细

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

My textbook has this sentence:

```
是一种很细很细的针。
```

(1) What is the purpose of "很细很细"?

(2) In what kind of situations can this phrase be used?

Comment: 很细 means very thin, modifies the noun, 针, 很细很细 is a special usage, repeated modifiers, you can find more about it in this site

Comment: What is the purpose of "很细很细 -- same as "very, very small..."

Comment: @Jacod which sites can I find more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wayne Cheah wrote :

> What is the purpose of "很细很细" -- same as "very, very small..."

And that should be the answer. I would give more examples to support it

很细的针 a very small needle

很细很细的针 a very very small needle / a small small needle

很遠的地方 a far away place/ a place far away

很遠很遠的地方 a very very far away place/ a place far far away

很大的手 Very large hand (a big one)

很大很大的手 very very large hand (a huge one)

Comment: Can I use this structure in all situations?

Comment: It is kind of  use in something you can measure only. e.g. size, length...

Comment: @TangHo "something you can measure only. e.g. size, length" so I guess 一幅很美很美的画 wouldn't work?

Comment: I guess 一幅很美很美的画 works,  I did say 'kind of' . 很遠很遠 amplify the degree of distance, 很美很美 amplify the degree of beauty. Which is less common, compare to things we measure all the time,  like size and length